# Getting undefined reference errors while installing Caffe in Ubuntu 15.10 - is it caused by libtiff?

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, libtiff

I'm trying to install Caffe in Ubuntu 15.10. After cloning the [Caffe repository](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe), I copied `Makefile.config.example` to a new file, `Makefile.config`, and uncommented `WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1` in line 91.

Then, I executed

```
cmake .
make
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
Linking CXX executable caffe
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_num_locks@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_use_certificate_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_config@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey_file@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_load_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.52: undefined reference to `TIFFDefaultStripSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.52: undefined reference to `TIFFFdOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_set_ex_data@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_read@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFNumberOfStrips@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_set_flags@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSLv23_method@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_load_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFRGBAImageOK@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_check_private_key@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_by_id@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_locking_callback@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_load_error_strings@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_new@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_write@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `X509_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_set_verify@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_set_fd@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_table_name'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_connect@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ERR_reason_error_string@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_ctrl@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_pending@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_use_PrivateKey@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `ENGINE_finish@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_library_init@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5: undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/build.make:122: recipe for target 'tools/caffe' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/caffe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:406: recipe for target 'tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/caffe.bin.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Looking at the error messages, it seems that I need the `libtiff-4` package installed. I already have `libtiff5` and `libtiff5-dev` installed, and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37316325), it should be sufficient. However, it has not resolved the issue.

Is this the cause of the problem? If so, how do I correct it? If not, what should I do to resolve this?

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

Thank you